# Finding columns with null values in table for each database

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have table with columns like Databasename ,tablename,columnname,query. But in query column `SELECT COUNT(MachineName) AS Cnt FROM Keys WHERE  MachineName<>NULL`.
How to execute with this query column with in the table ( I need remaining 3 columns with executing of query column) can any one help me on this.

Comment: It is not fully clear what you are asking... Can you show what you have tried?

Comment: I have table with column names 'Databasename ,tablename,columnname,query' .But I want to execute a query stored in a table column ('Query') . I can execute with only Query column by using sp_executesql statement. But I need all columns with additional of dynamic query execute with another column

Comment: Storing queries in a table is a big red flag that something has gone horribly wrong in the design phase.

Comment: I am working some thing like DB cleanup, I need query that will return all null values data columns for table and this will run across all db's in my server

Answer (score 1):

Oh, I misunderstood. Are you searching for a query the executes the query in the query column and replaces some values in it with values from your database like following example:

```
if object_ID('tempdb..Test') is null
begin
    create table tempdb..Test (
    dbname nvarchar(512),
    tblname nvarchar(512),
    columnename nvarchar(512),
    query nvarchar(MAX)
    )


    --  delete from tempdb..Test
    insert into tempdb..Test (dbname, tblname, columnename, query)
    values ('master','sysobjects','id','select count([col]) from [db]..[tbl] where [col] is not null') 

    insert into tempdb..Test (dbname, tblname, columnename, query)
    values ('master','syscolumns','id','select count([col]) from [db]..[tbl] where [col] is not null') 
end


declare @db nvarchar(512)
declare @tbl nvarchar(512)
declare @col nvarchar(512)
declare @qry nvarchar(512)
declare @cmd nvarchar(512)

declare cur_test cursor 
    for select dbname, tblname, columnename, query
    from tempdb..Test
open cur_test

FETCH NEXT FROM cur_test   
INTO @db, @tbl, @col, @qry

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  
    set @cmd = replace(replace(replace(@qry,'[db]', quotename(@db)), '[tbl]', quotename(@tbl)),'[col]', @col)
    exec sp_executesql @cmd


    FETCH NEXT FROM cur_test   
    INTO @db, @tbl, @col, @qry
END

close cur_test
deallocate cur_test
```

Answer (score 0):

A comparison with null is done with the "is" or "is not" operator.

```
SELECT COUNT(MachineName) AS Cnt FROM Keys WHERE MachineName is not NULL
```

or if you want the entries where the column MachineName has an value then use

```
SELECT COUNT(MachineName) AS Cnt FROM Keys WHERE MachineName is NULL
```

Comment: This statement in 'SELECT COUNT(MachineName) AS Cnt FROM Keys WHERE MachineName is NULL' is in column data. I want to execute this with in table to adding another column is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You search for something like this:

```
select 'select count(*) from ' + QUOTENAME(so.name) + ' where ' + (SELECT QUOTENAME(Name) + ' is null and ' 
           FROM syscolumns sc
           where sc.id= so.id
            FOR XML PATH('') ) + '1=1' 
from sysobjects so 
where so.xtype='U'
order by so.id
```